# How to learn Just-in-Time compilation?

Tags: dynamic, compiler-construction, jit, compiler-optimization

There are lots of books that explain the traditional static compilation theories and techniques, but those books do not say much about Just-in-Time compilers.

Although reading source code of JIT is a way to learn, the code does not always explain backgrounds and problems to solves clearly. What is the best way to understand the infrastructures and principles (such as optimizations) of designing Just-in-Time compilers? In particular, I am more interested in the JITs for scripting languages or dynamic languages.

Any books or frameworks to recommend? As for looking into any concrete code, which JIT compiler is good to start with?

Thank you.

Comment: First understand static compilation and interpretation.  Then while interpreting, you'll come across cases where the fastest way to perform the operation is clearly to emit some machine code and call it.

Comment: I haven't seen books on the issue, but there is a wealth of papers, technical reports, theses, etc. which may seem very advanced initially (though it's mainly engineering, so you won't be buried in unexplained formulas) but are a very valuable resource.

Comment: Hi delnan, Would you like to recommend one or two such papers to start with? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about a book which has JIT explained in detail:
If you want to learn basics, following links would be helpful:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.zos.70.doc%2Fdiag%2Funderstanding%2Fjit_overview.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm

However, there is a Phd Thesis by Anshuman Das Gupta at Rice University, who did a lot of work on JIT, you might find a lot about JIT technology there:

http://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/20595

hth,